# file validations don't work properly in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms, validation

i created an customized validation in laravel 7 but the file validation didn't work properly.
i limited size and format in my validation and users observe the rules but when they submit form the validation system show them the errors related to file.

for example the file must not be bigger than 1 MB and the user upload less than 1 MB but form don't submit and show the customized message in validation.

the same thing happens about mimes and format

the other work properly.

my validation in controller :

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
       'customername'=>'required',
       'phone'=>'required',
       'producttype'=>'required',
       'width'=>'required',
       'height'=>'required',
       'model'=>'required',
       'material'=>'required',
       'count'=>'required',
        'sku'=>'required|unique:offlineorders,SKU',
        'image'=>'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg|size:1048',
    ],[
        'customername.required'=>'لطفا نام مشتری را وارد کنید',
        'phone.required'=>'لطفا شماره تماس مشتری را وارد کنید',
        'producttype.required'=>'لطفا نوع محصول را مشخص کنید',
        'width.required'=>'لطفا طول محصول را مشخص کنید',
        'height.required'=>'لطفا عرض محصول را مشخص کنید',
        'model.required'=>'لطفا مدل محصول را تعیین کنید',
        'material.required'=>'لطفا جنس بکار برده شده در محصول را تعیین کنید',
        'count.required'=>'لطفا تعداد سفارش را مشخص کنید',
        'sku.required'=>'لطفا شناسه سفارش را مشخص کنید',
        'sku.unique'=>'سفارشی با این شناسه از قبل ثبت شده است',
        'image.image'=>'فایل اپلود شده باید  عکس باشد',
        'image.mimes'=>'لطفا از فرمت های مربوط به عکس در فایل مربوطه استفاده کنید',
        'image.size'=>'عکس مورد نظر نباید بیش تر از 1 مگ باشد '
    ]);

 if ($request['image']){

     $file = $request['image'];
     $imgname = $file->getClientOriginalName();
     $this->ImageUploader($file, '/upload/orders/');
 }else{
     $imgname=null;
 }


    if ($request->has('paymentstatus')){
        $totalprice=$request->totalprice;
        $beforeprice=$request->beforeprice;
        $debatorprice=$totalprice-$beforeprice;
    }else{
        $debatorprice=0;
    }

    offlineorder::create([

        'ProductType'=>$request->producttype,
        'OtherProduct'=>$request->otherproduct,
        'CustomerName'=>$request->customername,
        'CorporateName'=>$request->corporatename,
        'Phone'=>$request->phone,
        'Width'=>$request->width,
        'Height'=>$request->height,
        'Model'=>$request->model,
        'Material'=>$request->material,
        'Color'=>$request->color,
        'Count'=>$request->count,
        'Kalaf'=>$request->kalaf,
        'Image'=>$imgname,
        'Text'=>$request->text,
        'Description'=>$request->description,
        'TotalPrice'=>$request->totalprice,
        'BeforePrice'=>$request->beforeprice,
        'PaymentStatus'=>$request->paymentstatus,
        'DebtorPrice'=>$debatorprice,
        'SKU'=>$request->sku,

    ]);

    session()->flash('add_order','سفارش شما با موفقیت ثبت شد');
    return back();
}
```

Comment: try this 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg|max:1048'. use max instead of size

Comment: yeah i try it first but it didn't work @sd077

Comment: What error you got after trying that

Comment: Did you use enctype=multipart/form-data in your form?

Answer (score 0):

According to Laravel 8 doc the line

'image'=>'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg|size:1048',

should be
'image'=>'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,svg|file|size:1048',

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-size

Maybe wrong file rule corrupts mime rule.